# Adobe Indesign - Can you print two half pages per 1 page of paper?

Tags: adobe, adobe-indesign

I would like to print out a document that I have created and would like the final printed document to be two halves (with appropriate margins) and be printed on a single 8.5 x 11 sheet of paper.

8.5 x 5.5 is the ideal paper size for me economically and I will be staying within that constraint.

I have tried booklet but I continue to get an error about paper sizes that the Adobe community says is a known bug.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had this problem with the booklet printing. The best solution is the following JS:

```
var doc = app.documents.length && app.activeDocument,
dpf = doc && doc.documentPreferences;
if( doc )
{
app.scriptPreferences.measurementUnit = MeasurementUnits.POINTS;
doc.pages.everyItem().reframe(
CoordinateSpaces.INNER_COORDINATES,
[[0,0],[dpf.pageWidth,dpf.pageHeight]]
);
dpf.facingPages &&
doc.pages.everyItem().move(
LocationOptions.UNKNOWN,
undefined,
BindingOptions.DEFAULT_VALUE
);
}
```

[All credit to Marc Autret](http://indesignsecrets.com/when-the-document-size-wont-change.php)

Once you have the pages all the same size you can use the booklet printing again.

[How to use a JS script in InDesign.](http://indesignsecrets.com/how-to-install-a-script-in-indesign-that-you-found-in-a-forum-or-blog-post.php)